# Wfp connection redirection memory allocated for associating context information is not getting freed

Tags: windows, wfp

I'm trying to make a kernel-mode callout driver that would redirect TCP traffic to a user-mode service. 
I've registered a callout at the FWPM_ALE_CONNECT_REDIRECT_V{4|6} layers. I am allocating memory for connection context and associating it with the connection which I am querying it from user mode service using SIO_QUERY_WFP_CONNECTION_REDIRECT_RECORDS
As per MSDN, I don't have to free the allocated memory, and its taken care of by windows (working with windows 10). Does this mean if I run the driver with driver verifier on, I won't get any complaint about my driver not freeing up memory before unloading!!
I found it in some scenario, DV does complain about memory not freed by my driver before unloading. How can I track when the allocated context memory is not being taken over by Windows?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/using-bind-or-connect-redirection

Thanks,